# KnockoutJS mapped Model add to Observable array

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to create an Observable Array from a Dynamic Model that is basically an AJAX post to obtain JSON info. I then want to add that Array to a table.

Here is my Javascript to create the Viewmodel, and what is suppose to add to array:

```
var ProductViewmodel;
    function bindProductModel(Products) {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        ProductViewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(Products, self.items);
        console.log(ProductViewmodel);
        ko.applyBindings(ProductViewmodel);
    }

    function JSONProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/AvailibleProducts",
            // Current Page, Method  
            data: '{Warehouse: 1}',
            // parameter map as JSON  
            type: "POST",
            // data has to be POSTed  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // posting JSON content      
            dataType: "JSON",
            // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
            timeout: 10000,
            // AJAX timeout  
            success: function (result) {
                bindProductModel(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The obtaining of the JSON works Perfectly:

```
{
"d": [
    {
        "__type": "Warehouse.Tracntrace.Members_Only.StockMovement.ProductStagingMethod",
        "ProductSKUID": 2,
        "ProductSKUName": "Decoder 1131",
        "WarehouseID": 1,
        "WarehouseName": "SoftwareDevelopmentTest",
        "SystemAreaName": "Staging",
        "Qty": 5
    }
]
```

}

and here is where I try to Data-Bind it to my Table:

```
<div id="TableContainer" class="gridview">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: ProductViewmodel">
       <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ProductSKUID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ProductSKUName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: WarehouseID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: WarehouseName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: SystemAreaName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: QTY"></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It seems that it does not want to add it to my array.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems with your code:

1. `data-bind="foreach: ProductViewmodel"` you try to foreach on the whole `ProductViewmodel` but you need to do it on the `items`. So change it to `<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">`
2. Your json objects wrapped inside a `d` property so you need to take care of it in your mapping. So you need to write: `ProductViewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(Products.d, self.items);`
3. You have misstyped the `Qty` property name. The correct binding is: `<td data-bind="text: Qty"></td>` (data bindings expression are case sensitive)

I've [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/Drhuc/) with your code which contains the fixes.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to use ko.mapping.fromJSON  instead of ko.mapping.fromJS?

Comment: I tried the ko.mapping.fromJSON, it doesn't seem to work for me. But always willing to give it a second go.